# Zip images on web server and return the url

Tags: google-cloud-platform, file-upload, webserver

I am currently looking for a way to improve the traffic flow of an app.

Currently the user uploads his data via the app, using Google Cloud Platform as storage provider. Other users can then download this data again.

This works well so far, but since the download traffic at GCP is relatively expensive I had the idea to outsource this to a cheap web server.

[image: Sequence diagram]

The idea is that the user requests the file(s) at GCP. There it is checked if the file(s) are already on the web server. If not, the file(s) will be uploaded to the server.
At the server the files are zipped and the link is sent back to GCP, where it is emailed to the user.

TL:DR My question is, how can i zip a specific selection of files on a web server without nodejs etc. and send the link of the generated file back to GCP

I'm open for other ideas aswell

Comment: It would depend on your environment but, you could run a scheduled job to look for new files and zip them proactively also generating some kind of index (db or just a config file of some sort) to map files to their archive.

Comment: The problem is that i can not just zip all files. For every user just a certain amount of files should be zipped regarding there selection

Comment: Why don't you use CDN to cache the files and thus reduce the egress?

Comment: But will the traffic to download the files not be the same?

Answer (score 0):

This is a particular case, covered by Google Cloud CDN (Content Delivery Network) service.
As you can read [here](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/setting-up-cdn-with-bucket), there already is a way to connect the CDN to a Storage bucket, and it will do exactly what you've thought to do with your own web server. The only difference is that it's already production ready. It handles cache misses, cache hits and so on.
You can compare the prices: [here](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/pricing) you can find CDN prices, and [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing) you can find Storage prices. The important difference is that Storage costs per TB of Egress, meanwhile CDN costs per 10TB of Egress, and the price is still lower.

Of course, you can still stick to your idea. I would implement it by developing a REST API. The API, with just one endpoint will serve the file, if it is present on the web server. If it is not present, it will:

- perform a redirect to the direct link for the file hosted in Storage;
- start to fetch the file form Storage and put it in the cache.

You would still need to handle the cache: what happens when somebody changes a file? That's something related to the way you're working with those files, so it strictly depends on your app functional domain, and in any case, Cloud CDN would solve it without any further development.